# Do I need to go out often to play Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I don't know much about the game other than the fact that you use your phones camera to interact with Pokemon as if they were in the real world.

That and despite the name, is the game playable if you don't get out often (i.e. in same location for most of the time)? When I am out I usually have data turned off because I don't have a large package.

Comment: You don't have to worry about your data draining when using Pokémon GO, people have tested it and about 0.01GB is drained every 1 hour.

Comment: @P1raten Interesting, source?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4oqjir/my_data_usage_with_pokemon_go/ I've played for a couple of hours and I'm at about 8mb.

Comment: On the other hand, instead of your internet package being drained, it drains your battery

Comment: @Taacoo it's "draining" your battery because the screen is on.  I'm pretty sure it'll drain just as fast if you turn off the sleep option for your screen.

Comment: @Nelson Pokemon Go comes with a save battery function in the menu. It will turn off the screen when you keep it upside down e.g. walk regularly with phone in your hand. It will then vibrate when you encounter a Pokemon

Comment: PGO has used about 10% of my 1G data plan so far (that started the day before it was released) and I've been playing a couple of hours a day. I think the amount of data it uses must relate to how many pokemon/stops you might actually encounter while out.

Comment: @P1raten Well I have 36MB used over a period of 48 hours and no, I haven't been playing for 36 hours. So that estimate is low

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the last few days to actually play the game and figure this out for myself.

### Can you play without going out often? **NO**

I'm talking about the average player, not someone who wants to buy a drone and strap their phone on it — or someone who is interested in spending loads of $$$ on in app purchases.

### Why?

It became apparent that while yes you can sit stationary and Pokemon do show up, you simply cannot ***progress*** in the game without moving.

**Pokestops** give you **Pokeballs**. If you only catch Pokemon as they pop up and never move about and visit Pokestops, you can't get more Pokeballs. Your only option then is to buy them.

**Incense** are items that attract Pokemon to your location. You get 2 to begin with, and only get another when you start to level up. Once they're gone, your only option is to buy them.

[image]

Gyms, I've found, are not essential to leveling up and playing the core game. So while you won't be able to use them without visiting them it doesn't really matter (early game at least).

And finally, if you don't catch Pokemon you won't get XP. Which means you won't level up. Your only option is in app purchases.

Note: Eggs require walking, biking, or very slow driving to hatch. There's no way to get around this, so basically this part of the game is off limits to someone who doesn't get out.

### Data Usage

I've been playing quite rigorously the last 96 hours, and according to my iPhone Pokemon Go has spent 6.4 hours on screen. My data usage, also according to to my iPhone, is 59MB. So for a whole month, if I continue playing as much as I do, I will use ~440MB. This seems fair, based on how much I've been playing.

### Battery

It eats up battery like no other. That's all there is to it. I've taken to using a portable battery pack.

Answer (score 10):

You do encounter some Pokemon when you are stationary for a long time but if you really want to catch stuff you'll have to walk around and visit spots.

Catching a lot of Pokemon is the (only?) way to get stronger in order to capture Gym's for your team (red, yellow or blue).

Some source: [link1](http://www.pu.nl/artikelen/nieuws/pokemon-go-gevechten-uitgelegd-en-een-hoop-nieuwe-screenshots-verschenen/)

Comment: Add some more info about how Gyms and how the location based _stuff_ works, possibly a source for the info, and I'll accept this

Comment: The source i have is a Dutch Gamereviewing magazine, so don't know if that is very credible.
The Gyms work the same as the capture points in Ingress. You have to leave a strong Pokemon at the Gym. The longer you hold it the more resources you'll get. Every 21hours you'll get resources like stardust and Pokecoins.

Comment: No that's good, put that in.

Answer (score 6):

The Answer is Yes ! You can Play Pokemon Go without Moving place to place but for that you have to setup a whole setup sounds wired hmm?

All you need is following things is a Laptop or pc, a drone or quadcopter and a mobile to run pokemon go and air droid app installed din your pc.

You can see the step from here [Play Pokemon Go without Moving place to place](http://www.gammerson.com/2016/07/play-pokemon-go-without-moving.html).
As I can't copy the images here.That how it will look like now you know how you can play Pokemon Go without moving.I know is not much practical for everyone but yes we can say that there is a way to play pokemon without moving.

Ps: Don't be lazy go outside and play safe.

Disclaimer: I am the team member of the source

Comment: Using a drone. That's amazing.

Comment: Ingress players already have done this.

Answer (score 1):

To get the best out of Pokemon Go you'll need to go outside to visit PokeStops and Gyms. While you can get Pokemon when you are stationary for a while you won't encounter them as much as if you'd go outside.

Answer (score 1):

No! You can actually considering walking around in your home and find a couple of Pokemon every now and then. I've myself caught 4 Pokemon around my house itself in the span of 2 days.

However, if you're looking for something like roaming around in the city and siting on sofa at the same time, it looks difficult. Though it's possible through a crook! Check this : [How To Play Pokemon Go Without Moving](http://www.letspokemongo.com/play-pokemon-go-without-moving-walking/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't move for a while you are able to use an incense which will spawn Pokémon near you. Those are obtained from PokéStops or the Shop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to move but the game dont uses much data. I have no large package too but i play it everyday for 3-4 hours and didnt got a message yet.